# How to add value in Input element using C# code in Aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, session, master-pages

I want to add value in `input` element, if session variable's value is not null

```
<input id="sessionInput" type="hidden" value='<%# Session["UserLogin"] != null ? Session["UserLogin"].ToString() : ""; %>' />
```

But it is not working.

**Error**

> ) expected

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon at the end. When using a Binding expression those are not needed.

```
<input id="sessionInput" type="hidden" value='<%# Session["UserLogin"] != null ? Session["UserLogin"].ToString() : "" %>' />
```

And you have to call `DataBind();` in the Page Load if you want the values to be bound to the Input.

Answer (score 0):

Use the newer `:` which html encodes the value.

```
<input id="sessionInput" type="hidden" value='<%: Session["UserLogin"] %>' />
```